# Return in try & catch versus return in finally?

Tags: c#, try-catch, return, finally

Is either one of these risky?  Is one better?  Or is it one of those things you print out and throw a dart at to decide?

I want to do this now that I understand how finally works:

```
try { 
    stuff that changes something... 
}
catch (System.Exception ex) { 
    something.worked = false; 
    something.err = ex.Message; 
}
finally { 
    stuff.close();
    return something; 
}
```

But I've seen:

```
try { 
    stuff that changes something...
    return something; 
}
catch (System.Exception ex) { 
    something.worked = false; 
    something.err = ex.Message; 
    return something; 
}
finally { 
    stuff.close(); 
}
```

Comment: @Dlev - Except the first isn't valid C# so it cannot be done.  So how can it be preferable?  This question really should be asked again, one where any code is actually valid code, otherwise its sort of pointless.

Comment: @Ramhound Oops, I meant that the former isn't legal C#. The latter is actually valid syntactically.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't `return` from `finally`. You will get compiler error:

> Control cannot leave the body of a finally clause

---

If target class implements `IDisposable` then I would do next:

```
using (stuff s = new stuff())
{
    return stuff;
}
```

or

```
using (stuff s = new stuff())
{
    try
    {
        // do stuff
        return stuff;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do logging or another stuff
        return something;
    }
}
```

will call `Dispose()` for you if that will be required/possible.

Comment: Doh!  Try compiling before you ask next time, Self!  It makes sense that control can't leave a finally since finally is so unique in demanding attention.

Comment: @user540903: Well, yes, you should have compiled it. But don't beat yourself up too badly; there are languages where return from finally is legal, and those languages have some pretty strange control flow semantics as a result. It is a reasonable question in general, just not for C#.

Comment: @Eric I'm pretty Java is one of those languages. From what I recall, the most recent `return` overwrites any previous ones, so `try { throw new BlahException(); } catch { return 1; } finally { return 2; }` actually returns a `2` to the caller.

Comment: @dlev: Right. JavaScript also allows returns from finally with the same semantics; last return wins.

Answer (score 17):

Personally I would do neither and would use

```
try { 
    stuff that changes something... 
}
catch (System.Exception ex) { 
    something.worked = false; 
    something.err = ex.Message; 
}
finally { 
    stuff.close();    
}
return something;
```

Also in the `finally` statement, check that you need to close/dispose of objects as they might have never been opened/set if they have failed.

Also see here [Is it bad practice to return from within a try catch finally block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449099/is-it-bad-practice-to-return-from-within-a-try-catch-finally-block)

Comment: I agree with this, as abatishchev says you can't return in a finally, i don't think you should have a return in a catch. If you have a try catch and don't rethrow you want it return either way and if you rethrow then it will never return anyway. Either way you only need 1 return statement not 2

Comment: returning from within the try/catch/finally is not considered "structured programming".  I agree with Tim and Ben.

Answer (score 0):

There is no risk in the second approach. But it allows you to return different values in case of exceptions.

Comment: So does returning a variable and setting it to different values in the try and catch blocks but only having 1 return outside the whole try/catach block.

Comment: returning the a value of a varible would also let you return different values in the case of exceptions.