# When is finally run if you throw an exception from the catch block?

Tags: c#

```
try {
   // Do stuff
}
catch (Exception e) {
   throw;
}
finally {
   // Clean up
}
```

In the above block when is the finally block called? Before the throwing of e or is finally called and then catch?

Comment: p.s. you should not "throw e;" because that will mess up the stack trace of the original exception.  You should just "throw;".  Or create a new exception and set the InnerException to "e" before you throw it.

Comment: *finally* would be a pretty poor choice of keyword if it didn't run *last*, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @ErvWalter is this still true? I am testing it both ways in VS2017, and it appears to be exactly the same. Could you provide some more information or a reference? Thanks

Comment: just naming suggestion use Exception ex - reserve e for events/delegates

Answer (score 197, accepted):

It would be called after e is re-thrown (i.e. after the catch block is executed)

editing this 7 years later - one important note is that if `e` is not caught by a try/catch block further up the call stack or handled by a global exception handler, then the `finally` block *may* never execute at all.

Comment: and never if you call Envrionment.FailFast()

Comment: After trying the code in Brandon's answer, I see that the `finally` is NOT executed if the exception thrown in the preceding `catch` is never *caught* in an outer `try`-`catch` block!

Comment: i remember that the finally got called at all cost, even after returning a value, did they change it?

Comment: Can you document how you know finally won't get called if exception is never caught?

Comment: They (Microsoft) talks about it on the new documentation site:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally:   "Within a handled exception, the associated finally block is guaranteed to be run. However, if the exception is unhandled, execution of the finally block is dependent on how the exception unwind operation is triggered. That, in turn, is dependent on how your computer is set up."

Comment: It seems its not as obvious - I tried running this 'DoIt()' method from Marc's answer from a unit test, without any outer try/catches and it **executes** the finally block. 
Not sure, maybe unit test methods have some kind of implicit catch mechanism?
(That was nunit + resharper runner + VS 2017)

Comment: @Bartosz - I believe the unit test runner is set up to catch exceptions inside of your test classes

Comment: Note that "caught by a try/catch block further up the call stack" will include framework handlers such as those in ASP.NET or a test runner. A better way of putting it might be "if your program continues to run after the catch block, then the finally block will execute."

Answer (score 122):

Why not try it:

This is the output from executing the code below:

```
outer try
inner try
inner catch
inner finally
outer catch
outer finally
```

with code (formatted for vertical space):

```cs
static void Main() {
    try {
        Console.WriteLine("outer try");
        DoIt();
    } catch {
        Console.WriteLine("outer catch");
        // swallow
    } finally {
        Console.WriteLine("outer finally");
    }
}
static void DoIt() {
    try {
        Console.WriteLine("inner try");
        int i = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(12 / i); // oops
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("inner catch");
        throw e; // or "throw", or "throw anything"
    } finally {
        Console.WriteLine("inner finally");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, for something so simple, you should really just try it like Marc has.  GJ illustrating it with nested try/catch/finally :)

Comment: @AllenRice why try it if Marc already has, and I can just google to find Marc's answer? Or maybe better, try yourself, then create an SO question and answer it yourself for others' benefit.

Comment: Please note that if you don't catch the exception in the outer catch, the inner finally is NEVER executed!! In that case, the output is `outer try` `inner try` `inner catch` `Unhandled Exception: System.DivideByZeroException...`

Comment: @Andrew you are right. The explanation you can find here [MSDN Magazine 2008 September: Unhandled Exception Processing in the CLR](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazine2008_09en-us.chm) (to open chm it need to unlock: File Properties -> General -> Unlock).

If you replace outer catch block with "catch (ArgumentException)" no one finally block won't be proceeded too, because CLR cannot find any "exception handler that agreed to handle the exception" DivideByZeroException.

Answer (score 51):

After reading all of the answers here it looks like the final answer is **it depends**:

- If you re-throw an exception within the catch block, and that exception is caught inside of another catch block, everything executes according to the documentation.
- However, if the re-trown exception is unhandled, the finally never executes.

I tested this code sample in VS2010 w/ C# 4.0

```
static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Example 1: re-throw inside of another try block:");

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--outer try");
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("----inner try");
                throw new Exception();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("----inner catch");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("----inner finally");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--outer catch");
            // swallow
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--outer finally");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Huzzah!");

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Example 2: re-throw outside of another try block:");
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--try");
            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--catch");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--finally");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Here is the output:

> Example 1: re-throw inside of another try block:
>   --outer try
>   ----inner try
>   ----inner catch
>   ----inner finally
>   --outer catch
>   --outer finally
>   Huzzah!
>
> Example 2: re-throw outside of another try block:
>   --try
>   --catch
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
>   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main() in C:\local source\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 53

Comment: Great catch, I wasn't aware of that!

Comment: Note that the last finally may run, depending on what you choose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46267841/480982

Comment: Interesting... On .NET Core 2.0, the finally part runs after the unhandled exception.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I've just done a test in both .NET Core 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.6.1 and they both run the finally after the unhandled exception. Has this behavior changed?

Comment: I just ran your test in .Net 5.0 with this result:

Example 2: re-throw outside of another try block:
--try 
--catch
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
   at FinallyTest.Program.Main() in \Program.cs:line 36  
--finally

The finally block runs on the second test

Answer (score 24):

Your example would behave identically to this code:

```
try {
    try {
        // Do stuff
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
} finally {
    // Clean up
}
```

As a side note, if you really mean `throw e;` (that is, throw the same exception you just caught), it is *much* better to just do `throw;`, since that will preserve the original stack trace instead of creating a new one.

Comment: I don't not think this is correct. Finally should be inside the outer try block not outside it

Comment: @MatthewPigram: What do you mean? The `finally` block will in fact run after the `catch` block (even if the catch block rethrows the exception), which is what my snippet is trying to illustrate.

Comment: from how I interpret his example he is attempting to do a try catch finally within another try block. NOT a try catch within a try catch finally

Comment: @MatthewPigram: My answer doesn't have any "try-catch-finally" construct at all. It has a "try-finally", and inside the `try` block of that my answer has a "try-catch". I'm trying to explain the behavior of the 3-part construct by using two 2-part constructs. I don't see any sign of a second `try` block in the original question, so I don't understand where you're getting that.

Answer (score 14):

If there is an unhandled exception inside a catch handler block, the finally block gets called exactly **zero** times

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     try
     {
        Console.WriteLine("in the try");
        int d = 0;
        int k = 0 / d;
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("in the catch");
        throw;
     }
     finally
     {
        Console.WriteLine("In the finally");
     }
  }
```

Output:

> C:\users\administrator\documents\TestExceptionNesting\bin\Release>TestExceptionNesting.exe
>
> in the try
>
> in the catch
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide
>   by zero.    at TestExceptionNesting.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\users\administrator\documents\TestExceptionNesting\TestExceptionNesting.cs:line 22
>
> C:\users\administrator\documents\TestExceptionNesting\bin\release>

I got asked this question today at an interview and the interviewer kept going back "are you sure the finally doesn't get called?" I was uncertain if it was meant a trick question or the interviewer had something else in mind and wrote the wrong code for me to debug so I came home and tried it (build and run, no debugger interaction), just to put my mind at rest.

Comment: Unless the thrown exception is caught in another catch somewhere higher up the stack, in which case it may execute if that thrown exception is handled... Or I might be wrong...

Comment: @tomosius, yes, that's what Brandon's answer explains. :)

Comment: @tomosius That's why I started by specifying "If there is an unhandled exception". If the thrown exception is caught somewhere then by definition we're talking about a different case.

Comment: This is not true. At least not for NET Core 3.1. A simple new console project with this code shows "in the finally" after the exception.

Comment: Interesting that the behavior has changed, .NET core didn't even exist when I posted ;)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to tell also is to debug your code and notice when finally is called.

Answer (score 1):

Testing with a C# Console Application, the finally code has been executed after the exception is thrown: The "Application Error Dialog" existed and after you chose "Close the program" option, the finally block was executed in that console window.
But setting the breaking point inside the finally code block, I can never hit it. The debugger keeps stopping at the throw statement.
Here is my test code:

```
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
          string msg;
          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("GetRandomNuber returned: {0}{1}", GetRandomNumber(out msg), msg) == "" ? "" : "An error has occurred: " + msg);
       }

       static int GetRandomNumber(out string errorMessage)
       {
         int result = 0;
         try
         {
            errorMessage = "";
            int test = 0;
            result = 3/test;
            return result;
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            errorMessage = ex.Message;
            throw ex;

         }
         finally
         {
            Console.WriteLine("finally block!");
         }

       }
    }
```

Debugging in VS2010 - .NET Framework 4.0

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, I have done this to ensure cleanup.

```
using System;
class Program
{
static void Main()
{
    FinallyThrow();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
static void FinallyThrow()
{
    // Get finally block to execute EVEN IF there is an unhandled exception
    Exception thrownEx = null;
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("try..");
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("catch..");
        thrownEx = ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("finally..");
        if (thrownEx != null) throw thrownEx;
    }
}
}
```

OUTPUT (after breaking to the unhandled exception)

```
try..
catch..
finally..
```

.[Finally always run even if unhandled exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFjpn.png)

Comment: You will get a new Stack Trace though; Rather throw a new Exception with thrownEx as the InnerException to preserve the inner Stack Trace