# Exception Handling in c# - try catch finally

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, exception

I am bit confused regarding the finally block. I know that finally block gets executed no matter if there is an exception or not.

I have got 2 scenarios :-

1) If there is an exception in try block and I have not written any catch block for this try block, but I have a finally block, then will the finally block gets executed? Does finally block executed if the exception is unhandled?

Below is an example code :-

```
static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int x = 0;
                try
                {
                    int divide = 12 / x;
                }
                //catch (Exception ex)
                //{
                //    int divide = 12 / x;
                //    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                //}
                finally
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("I am finally block");
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

2) Will the finally block get executed if there is an exception in catch block?
Below is the sample code :-

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 0;
        try
        {
            int divide = 12 / x;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            int divide = 12 / x;   // this will throw exception in catch block
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am finally block");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I have tried these codes and I don't see the finally block getting executed.
Please explain me why the finally block is not executed.

Comment: Debug to see...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP basically asks for a tutorial on error handling which could be testes by himself fairly easily.

Comment: @ThierryV : Please read my entire post. I did debug and found that finally block is not getting executed. Wanted to know the reason.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally

Comment: The documentation specifically mentions that if there's no top-level catch block, it's not guaranteed that the `finally` block would execute. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question (although a duplicate). Please justify your downvotes. If you're not willing to or can't answer, please let others to do so.

Comment: @siddharthchakraborty thanks for the question. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1555567/201088

Comment: My answer is below and I don't downvote this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In really simple terms, these are what `try-catch-finally` blocks do:

### Try

The place where you'd put potentially problematic code. If an exception is generated, an exception will be thrown.

### Catch

Catch is the ONLY block where an exception will be *caught*. Hence the name. So when an exception is thrown, if you want to *ensure* the program doesn't 'hang', you must `catch` the exception.

### Finally

Do your cleanup. If, say, you have some array in your `try` block and you want to clean it up in case of an exception, this is the place to do it.

### Try-Finally

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally) says:

> Within a handled exception, the associated finally block is guaranteed to be run. **However, if the exception is unhandled, execution of the finally block is dependent on how the exception unwind operation is triggered.** That, in turn, is dependent on how your computer is set up.

Meaning, if you don't catch your exception, it depends on the situation whether `finally` is run.

So, with that in mind, let's look at your first code block.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 0;
    try
    {
        int divide = 12 / x;
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am finally block");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You're attempting to do a divide by zero which generates an exception. But there's no place for it to be 'caught', so the program hangs:

[image]

So if you add a `catch` block here, now it will allow for smooth sailing and go to your `finally` as well.

```
try
{
    int divide = 12 / x;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Oops. Division by Zero.");
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("I am finally block");
}
```

Now let's take your second code snippet. I'm going to do a small modification and flip the order of two lines of code inside the `catch`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 0;
    try
    {
        int divide = 12 / x;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        int divide = 12 / x;
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am finally block");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now, the `catch` block catches the exception thrown by the first illegal division and prints a message. But then there's a second illegal division inside the `catch`, and there's no catch for that thrown exception so the program hangs.

So if you modify it to have a second `try-catch` inside the first `catch` like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 0;
    try
    {
        int divide = 12 / x;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            int divide = 12 / x;
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex2.Message);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am finally block");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now it will catch both exceptions and you're good to go.

So the idea is, if you have a `try` you should try to have a `catch` unless you can justify why you don't want one.

Comment: Thank you.... This explanation cleared a lot of my doubts..cheers!!!

Comment: Happy to have been of help. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: here's no place for it to be 'caught', so the program hangs. But the finally code must be executed

Answer (score 0):

Following the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally) MSDN

> Within a handled exception, the associated finally block is guaranteed
>   to be run

That means for `try catch finally`, the code in `finally` must be executed.

```
        int x = 0;
        try
        {
            int divide = 12 / x;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am finally block");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

With the output:

```
Attempted to divide by zero. // catch Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
I am finally block // finally
```

> If the exception is unhandled, execution of the finally block is
>   dependent on how the exception unwind operation is triggered. That, in
>   turn, is dependent on how your computer is set up.

That means it depends the exception thrown `finally` code will be executed or not. If `StackOverflowException` or an exception i.e `ExecutionEngineException`, which may invoke to call Environment.FailFast() or Environment.Exit(), your `finally` code won't be executed because your application has closed before.

In your case 2, there is an exception `DivideByZeroException` in `catch` or in `try` in the case 1 , the code `finally` in this case will be executed.

```
int x = 0;
try
{
    int divide = 12 / x;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    int divide = 12 / x;   // no handled
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("I am finally block");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

The output:

```
I am finally block // finally
Run-time exception (line 16): Attempted to divide by zero. // exception non handled catch by the level plus high that cause crashing the application
```