# statements in finally block

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [try catch finally question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304308/try-catch-finally-question)

if an exception is not caught, does the code statements are executed

```
try
{
  throw new Exception("test example");    
}

finally
{
  Console.WriteLine("finally block"); 
}
```

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304308/try-catch-finally-question/3304356

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345091/will-code-in-a-finally-statement-fire-if-i-return-a-value-in-a-try-block

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `finally` blocks run regardless of exception*.

Please see [try-finally (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx):

> The finally block is useful for
>   cleaning up any resources allocated in
>   the try block as well as running any
>   code that must execute even if there
>   is an exception. ***Control is always
>   passed to the finally block regardless
>   of how the try block exits.***

* *Note that this is not entirely true. Some exceptions, like a [`StackOverflowException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx) will terminate the process immediately. But for the sake of this discussion it is fairly safe to say that a `finally` block will always run.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Finally blocks are *always* executed.

Answer (score 2):

The only time when code in the `finally` block is *not* executed is when the power fails or the computer crashes before execution reaches it.

See http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/My-Tales.aspx

Comment: +1 for making the most accurate answer from a detail everybody omitted and most probably few people will care about.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, code in `finally` block is guaranteed to get executed even if an exception is thrown within the `try` block.