# .NET Will stop debugging run the code in the finally block?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, debugging, finally

Well, I've read (and learned) that the finally block doesn't always execute its code (even apart from pulling the plug).
FYI For more information, see [try catch finally question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304308/try-catch-finally-question)

However, what I haven't found:
Does my finally block get executed when I stop the debugger?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. When you stop the debugger before reaching the finally-block, it won't be executed.