# Will code in finally run after a redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Take for example the following code:

```
   try
   {
      Response.Redirect(someurl);
    }
    finally
    {
       // Will this code run?
    }
```

Will the code in the finally block run?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

Try it and see!

Answer (score 7):

It will run. Response.Redirect actually throws a ThreadAbortException, so that's why code after that will not run (except anything in a **finally** block of course).

Answer (score 6):

Simple enough to test:

```
try
{
  Response.Redirect(someurl);
}
finally
{
   File.WriteAllText("C:\\Temp\\test.txt", "The finally block ran.");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It will indeed.  See this MSDN article:  [Finally always executes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: "Finally always executes."  Well, not _always_.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216046/does-the-c-finally-block-always-execute

Comment: @David Touche. Finally always executes, barring a catastrophe beyond the CLR's control.  Better? :)

Comment: @Dave: It's just a fun subject to contemplate, isn't it?  I may use it as an interview question the next time I find myself doing a technical pre-screen on a candidate: "Does a 'finally' block always guarantee execution, and if not then in what cases wouldn't it?"  So far I can think of 7 distinct (though some of which are closely related) scenarios that would prevent it.

Comment: @David I posted the scenario where try and finally have differing return values on the whiteboard in my office.  It ended up nerd-sniping more coworkers than I was expecting and generated a lot of interesting conversation.  What are your 7 scenarios?  Everything I can think of involves either forcefully killing a running process or removing the machine's power source.  I'm very curious to hear some more, though.

Comment: @Dave: StackOverFlowException, OutOfMemoryException, ExecutingEngineException, Environment.FailFast(), Process/Thread is killed by an external process/thread (not thread abort, which will attempt to execute the finally block, but a low-level termination of the thread with extreme prejudice), Infinite loop within the try block (most likely a precursor to the previous one), and power failure.

Comment: @David Very interesting - I'll keep this thread in mind the next time my coworkers get into a discussion on ways to royally screw up our code (in theory, of course :))

Answer (score 3):

Why do you not just try it?

`finally` **always** runs, except in these extreme scenarios:

- Total application crash, or application termination (e.g. FailFast())
- A limited number of serious exceptions
- Threads getting terminated (eg. Thread.Abort())
- Hardware failure (e.g. machine losing power)
- Infinite loop inside the try-block (which ultimately results in application termination)

Comment: Oh no, not this argument again :)  There are several instances in which a "finally" block would not run.  It's been discussed before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216046/does-the-c-finally-block-always-execute

Comment: Edited answer to be a bit more precise.  Still, except in EXTREME cases, finally *always* runs.

Answer (score 3):

The code in the finally will run, but it will run *before* the redirect, since the redirect won't be sent to the browser until the method returns, and the finally code will execute before the method returns.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
try
{
  Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
finally
{
   // Will this code run?
  // yes :)
  Response.Redirect("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668422/will-code-in-finally-run-after-a-redirect");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Code in the `finally` is guaranteed to run, unless something catastrophic happens.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Here is how you can check if I am right or not. Simply place a message box or write something to the console from finally and you will have your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is that the code in finally will be applied in all cases (try/catch)