# Response.Redirect() inside a try-finally

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect, try-finally

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will code in finally run after a redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668422/will-code-in-finally-run-after-a-redirect)

Hello,

What happens when I call a Response.Redirect() with EndResponse set to true/false inisde a try/finally block? Will the finally be called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `finally` block in a try/finally will **always** be called - that's the point of `finally`.

Exceptions (minor) are described here: [Conditions when finally does not execute in a .net try..finally block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111597/conditions-when-finally-does-not-execute-in-a-net-try-finally-block)