# What is the finally block for compared to just writing code after the try statement?

Tags: c#, javascript, try-catch-finally

In other words, how are these two different?

```
try
{
    // Something that can throw an error
}
catch
{
    // Handle the error
}
finally
{
    // Something that runs after the try statement
}
```

vs.

```
try
{
    // Something that can throw an error
}
catch
{
    // Handle the error
}
// Something that runs after the try statement
```

Comment: Finally is used if catch errors out.

Comment: Have you ever had try-finally without catch?

Comment: When using a try block the code in the finally block is guaranteed to run whether an exception occurs or not.

Comment: I'm sure this is available here and elsewhere already, but which language do you want answers for?  There may be subtle differences between C# and JavaScript.

Comment: This is an obvious case of RTFM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx

Comment: [MDN try/catch/finally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: Did you even Google for the documentation's take on it first?

Answer (score 2):

`finally` block always executes.

You can be sure, that this block will be executed no matter what.

Literally it is something like:

> Try something, catch some exceptions(if told to and if they are there) and execute the
>   finally block finally.

Comment: +1, But there *are* extreme cases where `finally` may not execute. See [Does the C# "finally" block ALWAYS execute?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3216078/735425)

Answer (score 1):

If there is a break in the try block or an exception, it may cause the program to halt. In cases like these code that is mandarory to be executed, like closing open connections and returning items to the connection pools are writen in the finally block. The finally block ensures that the code written inside it will be executed.

Answer (score -1):

If you only ever use general catches (i.e. `catch` without args or `catch(Exception ex)`), whether to put code in `finally` or after `try/catch` is basically a stylistic choice, as both a `finally` block and code after a `try/catch` will execute in any situation (barring deliberate escape mechanisms such as `return`).

However, if you use a narrow `catch`, and the exception isn't caught, what will happen is the `finally` block will still execute, however the code after the `try/catch` won't.

Comment: This is not true.  Any form of flow control (`goto`, `continue`, `break`, `return`, `yield break`) would be able to bypass such a non-finally finally block.  This would *only* protect you from `throw` as a flow control mechanism.

Comment: Yes, but that's not my point--my point is that the flow between following a `try/catch` block with a `finally` block will be the same as if you just put code after the `try/catch`, which I believe is what's confusing the questioner.  The difference between using a `finally` or not arises when you use a narrower form of `catch()`.