# Is finally in Python added just for better readability

Tags: python, exception

On this link (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) following is said:

> A finally clause is always executed before leaving the try statement, whether an exception has occurred or not.

CODE 1:

```
try:
    print "Performing an action which may throw an exception."
except Exception, error:
    print "An exception was thrown!"
    print str(error)
else:
    print "Everything looks great!"
finally:
    print "Finally is called directly after executing the try statement whether an exception is thrown or not."
```

OUTPUT 1:

```
Performing an action which may throw an exception.
Everything looks great!
Finally is called directly after executing the try statement whether an exception is thrown or not.
```

CODE 2:

```
try:
    print "Performing an action which may throw an exception."
    raise  Exception('spam', 'eggs') # This is new
except Exception, error:
    print "An exception was thrown!"
    print str(error)
else:
    print "Everything looks great!"
finally:
    print "Finally is called directly after executing the try statement whether an exception is thrown or not."
```

OUTPUT 2:

```
Performing an action which may throw an exception.
An exception was thrown!
('spam', 'eggs')
Finally is called directly after executing the try statement whether an exception is thrown or not.
```

What I get from this is that `else` is executed only when there is no exception.

**QUESTION:**
Is `finally` used just for better readability ?
Because I can just put this print statement after try, like in this code.

CODE 3:

```
try:
    print "Performing an action which may throw an exception."
    #raise  Exception('spam', 'eggs') # with this line or without last print is done
except Exception, error:
    print "An exception was thrown!"
    print str(error)
else:
    print "Everything looks great!"

print "Finally is called directly after executing the try statement whether an exception is thrown or not."
```

Comment: The print statement would not be executed if any of the code *returned* if in a funcction, or used `continue` or `break` if in a loop.

Comment: Isn't the finally statement there for clean-up purposes? Moreover, [isn't it the same in java?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we need the "finally" clause in Python?](/q/11551996/90527)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are circumstances where the `finally` suite is **always** executed, but your `print` statement would not:

1. When there is an *unhandled* exception in your `try`.
2. When your `try` is in a loop (`while` or `for`) and you used a `break` or `continue` statement
3. When your `try` is in function and you used a `return` statement.

The `finally` suite then is used to **guarantee** that code is executed, regardless of what happens in the `try` block, even when exited before reaching the end of the block.

Compare:

```
def foo():
    try:
        print "Performing an action which may throw an exception."
        return
    except Exception as error:
        print "An exception occured!", error
    finally:
        print "Cleaning up"
```

with

```
def bar():
    try:
        print "Performing an action which may throw an exception."
        return
    except Exception as error:
        print "An exception occured!", error
    print "Cleaning up"
```

In `bar()` the last message is *not* printed:

```
>>> foo()
Performing an action which may throw an exception.
Cleaning up
>>> bar()
Performing an action which may throw an exception.
```

Comment: Is `sys.exit` a fourth? (or is that covered by unhandled exception?)

Comment: @GP89: `sys.exit()` throws an exception, so that falls under the unhandled exception case.

Comment: can you provide some code example where my print statement from `CODE 3`, would not be executed, that I thing I will get it. Thanks

Comment: @WebOrCode: added an example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah but this goes against the single return point paradigm! :P

Comment: @MartijnPieters I get it with `return` statement. But I still can not think of real world example of it. Why to put `return` in `try` ?

Comment: @WebOrCode: Before we had context managers, it was the correct way to ensure that a file is closed whatever happens in the function. `f = open(...)` then put everything in a `try` with `finally: f.close()` at the end.

Comment: @WebOrCode: the alternative is to always catch *all* exceptions then re-raise after closing the file, *and* closing the file when the code ran successfully. That's not efficient and you end up repeating yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The finally code block is always executed, whether or not an exception is thrown. This is true in most (I wanted to say all but ...) other languages: [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216046/does-the-c-sharp-finally-block-always-execute), [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java), etc.

Its function is to allow the execution of clean-up code -- close opened resources, de-allocate memory, etc. -- for the program to continue/terminate its execution in a clean and safe way.