# How is memory handled when we return from a method in a `using` block?

Tags: c#, memory-management

Consider the following code:

```
public Bar GetBar()
{
    using(var foo = new Foo())
    {
        return foo.Bar;
    }
}
```

Is this leaky, or is `foo.Dispose()` called? Is it possible that the return value is invalid as a result of `foo` being disposed?

Comment: What do you do in the Dispose method of the Foo class with the Bar instance?

Comment: @Steve - For the sake of discussion say we're unsure; maybe it calls `Bar.Dispose()` or something of the like.

Comment: If Foo.Dispose disposes Bar then you cannot use it outside the using. If not then you are safe using the reference to Bar. Until a reference to the memory occupied by the Bar instance exists.

Comment: [Interesting, related Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/345270/1081897) from a comment on one of the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers here are close but not complete and are inconsistent.

> Is this leaky, or is foo.Dispose() called?

`Dispose` is called.  The `using` block gets converted to a `try`/`finally` block in which `foo` is disposed of in the `finally` section.  `finally` will be called after the `try` completes (whether by exception or naturally) and before returning to the caller.  So `Dispose` will be called in virtually every situation (barring very serious exceptions such as out of memory, thread aborts, etc.)

> Is it possible that the return value is invalid as a result of foo being disposed?

Sure, if `Dispose` does something to invalidate the object that `Bar` references, then yes, it certainly could be returning an "invalid" reference.  But that would have to be *explicit* within `Foo`.  Disposing of an object does not automatically dispose of all properties.

Comment: I was unaware of the `using`->`try...finally` conversion, and the behavior detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345091/will-code-in-a-finally-statement-fire-if-i-return-a-value-in-a-try-block/345270#345270)... all makes sense now, though - thanks for the synopsis!

Answer (score 2):

> Is this leaky

No.  This is good coding practice for *almost* any object implementing IDisposable because it ensures that the dispose method is called as soon as the variable being 'used' goes out of scope (eg. the code leaves the using block).  There are a few exceptions (WCF clients, custom code that doesn't follow good IDisposable practices), but it is a good idea to wrap ANY IDisposable in a using block unless you have a specific reason not to.

> Is it possible that the return value is invalid as a result of foo being disposed

This depends on what the `Dispose` method in Foo does.  For example, if you try to invoke a SQLCommand that references a SQLConnection that has already been closed/disposed, you are going to get an exception.  Lets look at an example that makes this behavior obvious.

```
public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    public Foo()
    {
        ComplexType = new ComplexType();
    }

    public ComplexType ComplexType { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ComplexType = null;
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Now this piece of code that accesses our Foo:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo;
        ComplexType complexType;

        using (var newFoo = new Foo())
        {
            foo = newFoo;
            complexType = newFoo.ComplexType;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(complexType.SomeProperty); // This works :)
        Console.WriteLine(foo.ComplexType.SomeProperty); // Throws an exception because ComplexType is NULL

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Weird right?  The reason this happens is because in the Foo constructor we create a new ComplexType and store it at a memory address.  The Foo.ComplexType property contains a *reference* to the memory address.  When we call dispose, we set the *reference* to null, but the actual object is not garbage collected because we have other references to it in our calling code, so we can't access it through the `foo.ComplexType` property anymore, but it is still accessible via the `complexType` variable.  Note as well that `foo` is NOT null even though it has been assigned to an object that has been disposed.  Because a reference still exists to our `Foo` instance, despite being outside of the using block, it is still alive since it can't be collected while that reference exists.

Now, if the `Dispose` method changed SomeProperty, it is possible (depending on how it was changed), that the change COULD propagate out and invalidate results.

I guess the moral of the story is that you *could* experience (or create) all sorts of weird behavior if you start playing around with objects that have been disposed, but that depends on what the disposed objects are doing during disposal.  I wouldn't recommend it as a practice since most objects aren't intended to be used after disposal.  Perform your "work" as an atomic unit inside the using block, and then let the object die.

Comment: 'though it has been assigned to an object that has been disposed' - rather 'assigned an' object I think if my English servers me well. And while true we shouldn't advertise using foo outside as it's Disposed for all intents and purposes (by the 'contract' made on it, so it shouldn't be used any more regardless). Also that gives away a wrong impression sort of. You put an 'equal sign' in between that and returning a property from within using, which isn't right, return from using is used quite often if the developer knows the details of the foo (or is trusted it will behave that way).